# simulating "ls -l | sort -r" using pipes in C

Tags: c, unix, pipe

This is an assignment so I will not ask specifics.

For this part of the assignment, I need to use pipes to "pipe" sort -r to ls -l.

I know how to do execl, but I can't fathom the idea of what it means to pass "output of an execl" to another execl using pipe.

Can somebody reccomend some readings on how to do accomplish this?

I tried googling many different things but I just can't understand it.

I also tried looking at different explanations of pipes but all of them make no sense to me.

If somebody can suggest any good readings that can help somebody who has no idea about how pipes work(other than passing things via command line with |) understand pipes, I would appreciate it.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ask to solve an assignment

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can see a pipeline like a producer and consumer.
Look this simple example. In this code, the parent process writes some string in the pipeline and the child process reads it and print it in the output.
What you want to do is close to this, the parent expect the first command and the child execute the second. But, you can make it more advanced by making that the child execute more than one command.
[other example](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/procfiles/pipe-example.c)

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    /*

 Read characters from the pipe and echo them to stdout. */

    void
    read_from_pipe (int file)
    {
      FILE *stream;
      int c;
      stream = fdopen (file, "r");
      while ((c = fgetc (stream)) != EOF)
        putchar (c);
      fclose (stream);
    }

    /* Write some random text to the pipe. */

    void
    write_to_pipe (int file)
    {
      FILE *stream;
      stream = fdopen (file, "w");
      fprintf (stream, "hello, world!\n");
      fprintf (stream, "goodbye, world!\n");
      fclose (stream);
    }

    int
    main (void)
    {
      pid_t pid;
      int mypipe[2];

      /* Create the pipe. */
      if (pipe (mypipe))
        {
          fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      /* Create the child process. */
      pid = fork ();
      if (pid == (pid_t) 0)
        {
          /* This is the child process.
             Close other end first. */
          close (mypipe[1]);
          read_from_pipe (mypipe[0]);
          return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
      else if (pid < (pid_t) 0)
        {
          /* The fork failed. */
          fprintf (stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      else
        {
          /* This is the parent process.
             Close other end first. */
          close (mypipe[0]);
          write_to_pipe (mypipe[1]);
          return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A pair of pipe contains two ends, whatever the program writes into one end end will be received at another end.

Your duty is make `ls -l` write to an end, and `sort -r` read from another end.

```
int p[2];
pipe(p);

if (fork() == 0) {
    // first child, run ls, so its output(fd 1) should be redirected to a pipe end
    dup2(p[0], 1);
    close(p[0]); // just for safety
    close(p[1]); // just for safety
    execvl("ls", ...);
}

if (fork() == 0) {
    // second child, run sort, so its input(fd 0) should be redirected to another pipe end
    dup2(p[1], 0);
    close(p[0]); // just for safety
    close(p[1]); // just for safety
    execvl("sort", ...);
}

close(p[0]);
close(p[1]);
```

Comment: Are you mapping the read end of the pipe to standard output and the write end to standard input?  You should have at least an exit operation after the `exec` operation, and probably an error message too.  And the letters `l` and `v` are mutually exclusive in `exec` operations.  It looks as though you have `execlp()` in mind rather than `excevp()`, but it depends on what's in those triple dots.

Comment: why does all code after dup2 calls "close" on the two array indexes?

Comment: @Dmitry because we don't need them any more

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is just an example, sure you will need lots of error check in the real code

Comment: I'm getting bad file descriptor errors... Still got to do more research...